# Polymorphic association for an either/or association vs. two separate rows with one null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and was trying to implement a polymorphic association. Basically, I have a device object which can belong to either a outlet or a port, but not both. From my understanding, a polymorphic association would be the way to do this, so I modeled it like this:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :io, polymorphic: true
end

class Outlet < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :device, as: :io
end

class Port < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :device, as: :io
end


  create_table "devices", force: :cascade do |t|
        ...
        t.integer "io_id"
        t.index ["io_id"], name: "index_devices_on_io_id"
      end
```

Now, I ran into some trouble trying to assign an `outlet` or `port` to the device's `io`:

> can't write unknown attribute `io_type`
>
> ```
>   @outlet = Outlet.where(id: @outlet_id).first
>
>   @device.io = @outlet
>
>   if @device.save
>   redirect_to @device
> ```

which is from

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @device = Device.new(io_id: params[:io_id])
    end
    
    def create
        @outlet_id = params[:device][:io_id]
        @device = Device.new(device_params)
        
        @outlet = Outlet.where(id: @outlet_id).first

        @device.io = @outlet

        if @device.save
        redirect_to @device
      else
        render 'new'
      end
        
  end
```

Now, I will gladly accept some help on why this error was thrown, but that's not my primary question. I had a thought while debugging this-- does it even matter if I don't use a polymorphic association here? Would it also be fine just to create two separate associations on my `device` table, one pointing to the `port` table and the other to the `outlet` table and make them both optional? One would remain null and the other would be assigned, and then I could check which field != null in my business logic. Will I run into problems down the road going this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Device` needs both an `io_id` and an `io_type`. Otherwise, how would `Device` know what kind of thing the `io_id` belongs to?

Currently, as shown by your migration, you only have `io_id`. And so, you're getting the unknown attribute error for `io_type`.

You should add `io_type` to your table and you should be good to go.

I suggest you modify your `create` action to be more like (with some comments):

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @device = Device.new(io_id: params[:io_id])
  end

  def create

    # how do you know the :io_id is for an Outlet and not a Port?
    # if you add a hidden field that includes io_type, so that
    # params[:device] = {io_id: x, io_type: 'Outlet'}, then you 
    # should be able to do something like:
    @io = params[:device][:io_type].constantize.find_by(id: params[:device][:io_id])

    # the has_one association provides the build_device method.
    # if you use this method, then io_id and io_type will 
    # automatically be set on @device
    @device = @io.build_device(device_params)

    if @device.save
      redirect_to @device
    else
      render 'new'
    end

end
```